# Screen Flow Number component is not updating

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

I had created screen flow with three component.
[image: Screen Flow]

**Component 1:Start Date**
Type- Date Component
[image]

**Component 2:End Date**
Type- Date Component
Default Value - Formula(Start Date + Days Left)
[image]

**Component 3:Days Left**
Type- Number Component
Default Value - Formula(End Date - Start Date)
[image]

The following logic is working fine when I update the closed date then the days left are calculated according to the formula or vice versa but when I update the when start date the days left are not updating.
Seems like reactivity is not working when I update the start date.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to calculate recursive formula which is not possible.
Closed Date = Start Date + Days Left
Days Left = Closed Date - Start Date

*Scenario 1*:
User Input : Start Date = 02/11/2023
User Input : Closed Date = 03/11/2023
Now, As per formula Days Left = Closed Date - Start Date will give 1 as value.
Which is working fine.

*Scenario 2:*
Don't clear Above values and change value of Days Left.
User Input : Days Left = 2
Now, As per formula Closed Date = Start Date + Days Left will give Date as 04/11/2023

*Scenario 3:*
Don't clear Above value and change Start Date.
User Input : Start Date = 01/11/2023
Now, there are two formulas which needs to calculate and both are dependent on each other.
Closed Date = Start Date + Days Left ---> Which is dependent on Days Left
Days Left = Closed Date - Start Date ---> Which is dependent on Days Left
Which is practically not possible.

**Solution 1:**
Simply remove Days Left as input cmp and display just output of DaysLeftFormula
[image]

**Solution 2:**
What you can do is Add one input between Start Date & Closed Date and Label it as "Add Days".
And Add one more dispayText component for Days Left Formula.

Where Add Days don't have any default formula
Where EndDateFormula = Start Date + Add Days which is default value for End Date
Where DaysLeftFormula = End Date - Start Date
[image]

> NOTE: Now It'll work as per your requirement but you may have to
> somehow hide Add Days cmp after changing it's value as it's not
> actually formula and will confuse end user.